ROS2: can rqt_graph and ros-bag be used in a PC-Raspberry like network?
ROS2: can rqt_graph and ros-bag be used in a PC-Raspberry like network?
At PC side, I have something like this which runs OK:
sudo docker run --net host -it --rm --name listener osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop /bin/bash
root:/# ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
[INFO] [1728208649.019188872] [listener]: I heard: [Hello World: 1]

At RPi side, I have something like this which runs OK:
sudo docker run --net host -it --rm --name talker ros_docker /bin/bash
root@raspberrypi:/# ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
[INFO] [1728208649.021155610] [talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'

Now, I a third docker container at PC side, I'd like to check the ROS graph with something like:
sudo docker run --net host --env "DISPLAY=:0" --volume "$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" --volume /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -it --rm --name analyse_listener_talker osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop /bin/bash
root:/# ros2 run rqt_graph rqt_graph
root:/# ros2 bag record -a


Command lines like ros2 run echo are OK but the rqt_graph is empty and the rosbag too: how to get this to work?
